# QGIS 3.8.3 - Create polygon with a specific width

Tags: qgis, polygon, area

I'm very new to GIS and QGIS.

I'm trying to map areas of arable fields and would like to create a polygon that traces the edge of a field and is a specific width away from the edge of the field ie 8 meters. Almost like drawing a line along the boundary then having a parallel line 8 meters away from the first line but making a polygon so I can work out the area.

I'm sure this is possible but im struggling to work out how to. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a buffer around the outer line of your polygon. You have at least two options to do so:

### Create Geometries with QGIS expressions

- Use [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (see here [for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) with this expression to create a polygon on **both sides** of the field's edges (inside **and** outside the field: blue area on the screenshot):

  ```
  buffer (boundary ($geometry),8)
  ```
- If you want to get only a 8 m distance **inside** the field (black dotted line), use this expression:

  ```
  single_sided_buffer (boundary ($geometry),8)
  ```
- And if you only want the area **outside** the field, use this last expression and change `8` to `-8`.

*Red lines: edges of the field; blue: buffer inside and outside; black dotted line: buffer only inside the field:*
[image]

### Use Geoprocessing tools

First convert the field polygon to lines using `Menu Vector / Geometry tools / Polygons to lines`. Then use one of these tools:

- Use `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing tools / Buffer` with Distance = 8
- Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Single sided buffer` to create buffers only **inside** (positive values for Distance) or **outside** the field  (negative Distance values).